# What exactly does the "show subsys" command show?

Tags: cisco-ios

According to Cisco IOS documentation, `show subsys` command displays the subsystem information which doesn't tell much. Is it basically a feature list for particular IOS image similar to one in *Cisco Feature Navigator*? What is the practical usage of `show subsys` command?

Few examples with `c1841-spservicesk9-mz.124-22.T.bin` can be seen below:

```
c1841#show subsys name bfd*
Name                Class     Version   
bfd                 Protocol    1.000.001     
bfd_registry        Registry    1.000.001     
c1841#show subsys name tcl 
Name                Class     Version   
tcl                 Library     2.000.001     
c1841#
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are software component versions. Unless you're Cisco, the information is 99% meaningless.

Comment: Thanks for response! Cisco has probably some internal documentation which maps those software components seen in `show subsys` output and their versions to features seen in _Cisco Feature Navigator_ and actual CLI commands?